# Can I handle missing values for an important variable differently for training and for testing dataset

Tags: python, linear-regression, data-mining, missing-data, training-data

I have a training and a testing dataset and I want to predict a variable Y.

I am still in the data cleaning process and I found that one of my important variable (that I will call: X) have several missing values in both datasets.
Instead of dropping X, I want to fill in those NA values by predicting it with a linear regression (with X as a dependent variable, and other variables as explanatory ones) and then put the fitted values instead of NA.

My question is: Will it create some bias to predict X with Y (and other variables) in the training-data, and not include Y to predict (missing values) X in the testing-data?

Indeed, if we do so we will have more precision for the training-data missing values of X, but we will handle differently the training-data & the testing-data missing values of X.

Comment: Is the data *missing* in the training/testing data, but will always be available to the model during inference, or is the data *optional* and may also be missing during deployment?